# Want to implement tabs in android?

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar, swipe, android-tabs

I am trying to implement swipe tabs in my application but don't know what is the best way to do it.I am confused as to whether I should action bar navigation bars or some other mechanism.
I want my application to have Scroll-able views like in the link below?

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.asus.todolist

Comment: Check this [Android's BottomNavigationView](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48202475/2032561)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **`uiautomatorviewer`** to determine what that app is using. My guess is that it is using a `ViewPager` with a `PagerTabStrip` for the tabs.

Comment: You can easily add tabs dynamically with ViewPager?

Comment: @afnan1992: That depends upon your implementation of `PagerAdapter` that you use. The stock `FragmentPagerAdapter` and `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` are IMHO not well suited to changing the mix of tabs dynamically. My `ArrayPagerAdapter` handles them well: https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-pager

Comment: This also is a suitable solution to my problem? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10114417/insert-and-remove-fragments-into-viewpager-properly?lq=1

Comment: @afnan1992: None of those would seem to be relevant, but perhaps I am not understanding your problem.

Comment: I want to add new fragment(tab) to the PageAdapter when some event gets triggered? I do believe the link I have given solves the current predicament.

Comment: You don't think I can achieve it with link I have given?